# Графический баг при переключении SwitchPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-support-library

Исчезает после смены конфигурации (поворот, повторное открытие активити -
 хоста).
[image: Скрин]

Активити - хост настроек:

В зависимостях прописаны эти версии support-preference либ:
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.0.1'

Активити - хост настроек:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActivityBaseStructure {

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new PreferenceFragment().newInstance((String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("preferences"));
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.settings_fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.settings_fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Фрагмент настроек:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActivityBaseStructure {

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new PreferenceFragment().newInstance((String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("preferences"));
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.settings_fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.settings_fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
<style name="ToolbarColor" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

preferences_general:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settings_general">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="switch_overlay_exercise_on_graph"
            android:summary=""
            android:title=""/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, будто рисуется 2 таких виджета один под другим.

Comment: Блин что-то с редактором кода не справился. Случайно вместо кода фрагмента вставил снова код активити - хоста. Сюда закинул код фрагмента. https://pastebin.com/iV44pLbq

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь. Я забыл убрать дублирующий код из абстрактного класса, который писал для помещения туда однотипного кода для назначения активити хостом. В итоге действительно дважды выполнялось наложение.
Проблема решена!